# Как организовать структуру реферальной системы в базе данных?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Всем привет. Подскажите, как правильно реализовать структуру реферальной системы?
Регистрация по реф. ссылке уже есть, новому пользователю записывается id пользователя, от которого он пришел.
Но надо сделать страницу, на которой пользователь может увидеть всю структуру, которая "под" ним (включая всех тех, кто регистрировался под теми, кого позвал наш пользователь и т.д.).

Линий в этой структуре должно быть не ограниченное количество, то есть, если спустя 10, 20 или 30 человек кто-то зарегистрируется в "моей" реферальной системе, то я должен его видеть в своей структуре.

Мне в голову пришло только 2 варианта решений:
1)Хранить у каждого пользователя id того, "под" кем он зарегистрирован, но тогда на странице структуры у меня будет огромное кол-во запросов к БД, чтобы по цепочке достать всех пользователей, их пользователей и т.д.

2)Сделать таблицу со связями, где будут создаваться записи при регистрации каждого пользователя для каждой линии отдельно.
Допустим, Иван позвал Андрея, а Андрей позвал Олега, а Олег в свою очередь позвал Михаила.
Вот при регистрации Михаила создавались бы в таблице записи примерно следующие:

```
userId - id Михаила.
refId - id Олега.
line - 1.

userId - id Михаила.
refId - id Андрея.
line - 2.
```

и т.д. по цепочке до Ивана, который был первым в этой структуре. Но тогда при регистрации будет слишком много запросов в базу данных, да и в принципе таблица превратится в свалку.

Подскажите, как правильно организовать хранение данных для реферальной системы с неограниченным количеством линий?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: *Регистрация по реф. ссылке уже есть, новому пользователю записывается id пользователя, от которого он пришел.* Всё, больше НИЧЕГО не нужно. При условии, что пользователи НЕ удаляются.

Comment: Пользователи не удаляются, но как тогда запросить всю структуру для пользователя? Ведь там по цепочке может быть огромное количество запросов.
Даже если представить, что первый пользователь позвал троих, а эти трое еще позвали пятерых и т.д, то будет огромное дерево с кучей запросов к БД.
Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: *но как тогда запросить всю структуру для пользователя?* В MySQL версии 8 есть рекурсивные CTE, которые легко строят дерево из исходных данных в формате parent-child. Если же не повезло, и версия - всего лишь 5-я, то для получения того же результата используется итеративная хранимая процедура. *будет огромное дерево с кучей запросов к БД.* Ну дерево по определению будет иметь столько же записей, сколько и исходная таблица. Это если никак не ограничивать выборку. Но раз выборка нужна по одному пользователю, то и записей будет поменьше. К тому же размер никак не зависит от способа получения.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно если перефразировать ваш вопрос, то будет он звучать так:

**Как сформировать многоуровневое меню**

Решение для данной ситуации, когда структура бд должна представлять собой `parent_child` где каждый ребёнок может являться родителем другому значению, следующее

Структура бд должна быть следующей:
Таблица users с колонками id, name, parent_id (это абстрактный пример, помимо id и parent_id колонок может быть сколько угодно, но эти две обязательны)
`parent_id` это ваш `ref_id` по сути

1. Анализируя структуру мы понимаем, что здесь связь 1 ко многим поэтому указываем в нашей модели `User` следующее:

   ```
   public function parent()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'parent_id');
   }
   ```
2. Никаких 1000 запросов в бд не будет. Будет всего 1 запрос на получение данных.

   ```
   $items = \App\Models\User::orderBy('parent_id', 'DESC')->get();
   ```

Сортировка по убыванию `parent_id` обязательно. Почему? Когда мы будем бежать в цикле и подставлять рекурсивно значения, если мы не отсортируем по убыванию, то 3 и дальше уровни вложенности пропадут (можете потом по экспериментировать). Далее мы получаем коллекцию всех пользователей системы.

3. Следующий этап это группировка по `parent_id` для того чтобы объединить сразу всех пользователей.

   ```
   $grouped = $items->groupBy('parent_id');
   ```

В результате мы получим

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1589 ▼
  #items: array:12 [▼
  "" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1496 ▶}
  36 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1486 ▶}
  34 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1585 ▶}
  30 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1588 ▶}
  27 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1600 ▶}
  16 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1590 ▶}
  ...
]
```

4. Далее мы пробегаем по всем элементам и проверяем есть ли дочерние элементы и добавляем их под ключом `children`.

   ```
   foreach ($items as $item) {
      if ($grouped->has($item->id)) {
        $item->children = $grouped[$item->id];
      }
   }
   ```
5. И последний этап это отдаём фронту получившийся массив. Избавляясь от всех элементов которые являются дочерними, так как они уже находятся в нужном месте при проходе цикла.

   ```
   view()->with('struct', $items->whereNull('parent_id'))
   ```

Итог: пример данного кода, можно найти в интернете, суть везде одна и та же.

На фронте данный массив вы выводите так же с помощью рекурсии проверяя наличие `children` ключа. Это Вам домашнее задание

Проблемы при формировании.

Что если пользователей будет 100000? Запрос отработает быстро, так как id является индексом и `parent_id` то же должен быть. В результате сортировка то же будет быстрой, нагрузка на бд будет не большая. НО! далее начинается обработка сервером что приводит к большому циклу плюс рекурсия (groupBy). И когда пользователи будут заходить на сайт они будут ждать пока загрузится данное меню, а потом только получать данные. При переходе на другую страницу будет то же самое.

Поэтому данную структуру надо создавать один раз и далее кешировать в файловой системе или redis к примеру или где хотите. И при создании или удалении пользователя, обновлять кеш и само меню. Лучше это делать с помощью очередей в фоновом режиме, чтобы пользователь не ждал.

При заходе на страницу пользователю будет отдаваться следующее:

```
view()->with('struct', Cache::get('user_structure'));
```

А когда изменяете таблицу, будет что-то типо метода. Данный код является `псевдо-кодом` и показывает всего-лишь суть генерации и хранения.

```
//Какой-то сервис генерации 

...

public function generateMenu()
{
    //код выше из ответа

   return Cache::rememberForever('user_structure', $result);
}
```